# Interesting D.E turns into Geometric Limit and Cyclic Group.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory

Me and a friend Observed some very odd behavior of a matrix when trying to solve an ODE

Consider first the 3x3 system where a,b are parameters in the Reals and fine the general solution.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & b \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ -b & 0 & a\end{pmatrix}$

Now a common method would be to just throw in some $\lambda$'s and take a determinant.

An odd choice that may work well is to write $e^{At}$ where A is a matrix now im not all that well versed in this method so please bare with the expansion.
first we split the matrix into

$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ one of the rules of this expansion is that if call the first matrix here $C_{1}$ and the second $C_{2}$ is that $C_{2}$$C_{1}$=$C_{1}$$C_{2}$ this actually work's out for us which was exciting at the time but lets take a closer look at $C_{2}$.

$C_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ the other basic idea of thsi formula is that $(C_{1})^{n}$= O

where $O=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Much to our dismay this never happens oddly you can actually define a infinite sequence here where the sum $(C_{1}^{2k})/2k!$ and $(C_{1}^{2k-1})/(2k-1)!$ and the function actually generates sin and cos's taylor expansion.

The other more interesting thing for me was that ( perhaps for the first time in my life i spotted an idea from set theory that wasn't completely engineered) you can treat $C_{1}$ as generator ie $<C_{1}>=G$ and you get a cyclic group G.

Now for my actually question/s

First Can you solve this ODE using set theory and what this means and explain it to me?

2) can someone construct an isomorphism from this group to anther group with labels that i can look up and go look at what that group means.

3) what is the identity?

I am very bad at anything and everything math but most of all set theory ( click on my profile if you don't believe me) i think if i could look at this with my understanding of the solution to this ODE it would give me a nice new light to look at groups with.

Comment: What is wrong with using $\lambda's$ with a to find the eigensystem or exponential for this matrix/problem as it is very straightforward?

Comment: For me set theory is just a thing i do in a class with no real application to any problem i have sat down and tried to solve. 
For me this represents something more then an answer to this ODE its a way i can look at set theory using a geometric object that this ode represents to me and that's well Fascinating.

I would never attempt to actually solve a question this way in a course or etc but looking at something in a different way is fundamental in pursuing knowledge especially in logic.

Also the exponential for this matrix cannot solve this ODE as i showed above.

Comment: What do you mean the matrix exponential cannot solve this ODE?

Comment: 1. This is representation theory. Set theory is about sets. 2. If you didn't find an identity, how do you know it's a group? 3. There's only one finite cyclic group of each order, denoted $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: if you take the matrix $C_{2}^{n}$ there exists an n such that $C_{2}^{n}=C_{2}$ is that not a cyclic group property? @Amzoti My text book states that the second term which i have Denoted $C_{2}$ must become the 0 matrix by multiplying $C_{2}$*$C_{2}$*$C_{2}$*....*$C_{2}$ some finite number of times this must yield the Zero matrix this never does that. it just flips around changing signs the formula in my textbook states that you cannot write $e^{At}$ unless that condition is satisfied.

Comment: Anyway if its a bad question i can delete it, i just thought it was very interesting.